Inserting data to Databricks using Simba Spark ODBC connection erroring when inserting to table with an Identity column
I am trying to insert data into a databricks delta table through Excel using the Simba Spark ODBC connection. I normally have no issues with it, but I am trying to use an Identity column on a new table and getting the error only when using the ODBC connection. I can successfully insert data using the databricks notebook.
The code used to make the table
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  ID BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
  ,DATE DATE
  ,TIME TIMESTAMP
  ,WHAT_FILE_WAS_UPDATED STRING
  ,WHAT_MODULE_WAS_IMPORTED STRING
  ,MODULE_ERROR STRING
  ,MODULE_RUN_TIME DECIMAL(15,13)
)

The code used to insert a record within databricks
INSERT INTO
  test_table (
    DATE,
    `TIME`,
    WHAT_FILE_WAS_UPDATED,
    WHAT_MODULE_WAS_IMPORTED,
    MODULE_ERROR,
    MODULE_RUN_TIME
  )
VALUES(
    '2024-04-01',
    '2024-04-01 11:15:59',
    'test string',
    'test string',
    NULL,
    '0.0000020345052'
  )

The VBA code to create the SQL statement
strSQL = "INSERT INTO" & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "  test_table(" & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    DATE," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    TIME," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    WHAT_FILE_WAS_UPDATED," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    WHAT_MODULE_WAS_IMPORTED," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    MODULE_ERROR," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    MODULE_RUN_TIME" & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "  )" & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "VALUES(" & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    '" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    '" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "'," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    '" & Replace(clrWB.FullName, "\", "\") & "'," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    '" & Replace(BAS_path, "\", "\") & "'," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    NULL," & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "    '" & MinutesElapsed & "'" & vbLf
strSQL = strSQL & "  )"

The error message received from VBA
[Simba][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Providing values for GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY column ID is not supported.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServerErrors$.runningQueryError(HiveThriftServerErrors.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.$anonfun$exec

The error mentions providing a value for the identity column is not allowed, but I am explicitly saying which columns I want to insert data into, and leaving the identity column out. If I copy the value of strSQL and paste it into databricks, the record is inserted.

Similar: https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/insert-into-a-table-with-an-identity-column-fails/td-p/28755

Or try using DEFAULT for ID as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68834080/478884
